How to exclude file less than x kB from a group read by glob
I think it's very simple but I can't figure it out.
In a python program to plot science meteo data I need to exclude some file of a list of text file.
I have hundred of file downloaded from a datalogger on the field. Sometimes the LTE link is degraded and instead of receiving a normal text file with normal header, I've something looklike HMTL (because I'm downling file with an URL API, an unreadable file could result in a sort of 404 error page downloaded, I guess).
Here a sample of a normal file with it's header:
"TOA5","2693","CR300","2693","CR300.Std.11.00","CPU:20240411_modem_steynard.CR300","4956","meteo"
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","T107_C_010_Avg","T107_C_150_Avg","T107_C_300_Avg","AirTC_Avg","RH","WS_ms_S_WVT","WindDir_D1_WVT","WindDir_SD1_WVT","SlrW_Avg","SlrkJ_Tot","Rain_mm_Tot"
"TS","RN","Deg C","Deg C","Deg C","Deg C","%","meters/second","Deg","Deg","W/m^2","kJ/m^2","mm"
"","","Avg","Avg","Avg","Avg","Smp","WVc","WVc","WVc","Avg","Tot","Tot"
"2024-04-18 00:00:00",788,6.492,"NAN",9.66,-1.336,86.2,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2024-04-18 00:10:00",789,6.446,"NAN",9.6,-1.314,88.1,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2024-04-18 00:20:00",790,6.411,"NAN",9.54,-1.379,91.1,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2024-04-18 00:30:00",791,6.373,"NAN",9.48,-1.433,90.1,0,0,0,0,0,0
"2024-04-18 00:40:00",792,6.343,"NAN",9.42,-1.553,90.2,0,0,0,0,0,0

And a 'false' file sample :
<html>
<head>

    <script language='JavaScript'>var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";

It's easy to see in a 'du -sh' bash command for example because false file are 4 kb and a normal file is approx 12 kb.
Here is the line I'm using in python to retreive all ile in a list
path = '/TEMPORARY/STMTO/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "*.dat"))

How can I exclude file less than 5 kb of all_files ?

You could be right, but It feel more complicated for me than just check the size (but I'm not a specialist).

because I'm downling file with an URL API, an unreadable file could result in a sort of 404 error page downloaded, I guess if it comes with non-200 status code you should if possible alter your collecting process, so it would dismiss such response

You can filter the files with a list comprehension:
all_files = [file for file in all_files if os.path.getsize(file) >= 5 * 1024]


It looks as though you want to distinguish between HTML and CSV files.
Rather than relying on the file size (which may not be a robust approach) you could try opening each .dat file and try to parse it as if it's HTML. If that succeeds, that's not a file that you're interested in.
Here's what I suggest:
from pathlib import Path
from html5lib import HTMLParser
from html5lib.html5parser import ParseError
from collections.abc import Iterator

DIR = Path("/TEMPORARY/STMTO/")

def getfiles(d: Path) -> Iterator[Path]:
    parser = HTMLParser(strict=True)
    for file in d.glob("*.dat"):
        try:
            with open(file) as fd:
                parser.parse(fd)
        except ParseError as e:
            yield file
        except Exception:
            pass

for file in getfiles(DIR):
    print(file)

Note:
You will obviously need to install html5lib (pip install html5lib) if you don't already have it
If you really want to base your selection on file size then it's just:
MINSIZE = 5 * 1024

def getfiles(d: Path) -> Iterator[Path]:
    for file in d.glob("*.dat"):
        if file.stat().st_size >= MINSIZE:
            yield file


Python standard library has csv.Sniffer which returns detected Dialect of given text or raise error if it fails to detect Dialect. I propose to use it in following way:
import csv
def is_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        text = f.read()
    try:
        csv.Sniffer().sniff(text)
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True

with disclaimer that Sniffer uses a rough heuristic and may produce both false positives and negatives. so it does not have to work in all cases. Please test it with some of your file and after that determine if it works acceptably for your use-case.
